# Notation for "is in bijection with"

Tags: notation

This might be a silly question, but is there any standard notation for a binary relation $\square$ such that for any two sets $X$ and $Y$, $X \square Y$ iff there is a bijection between $X$ and $Y$?

I cannot recall if I have ever seen a notation like this. Straightforward googling gives no results either.

(Of course, the need for this notation can be overcome easily in a variety of ways – I am just curious if an appropriate symbol for a binary relation exists as well).

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are then isomorphic in category **Sets**. Often in that case the notation $X\simeq Y$ is then practicized.

Comment: Any kind of symbol that 1) usually denotes some form of equivalence or congruence, and 2) is not already in use in your context, will do just fine as long as you say what you mean the first time you use it in your text.